# Laravel Filament v3 - I'm using spatie-laravel-translatable-plugin. I have problems with translation. Error => Cannot translate attribute `user_id`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I'm using the `mutateFormDataBeforeCreate` method in create action. There I did this - `$data['user_id'] = auth()->id();`
But when I add a new post and fill in the value for 2 languages and click on create it gives an error => Cannot translate attribute `user_id` as it's not one of the translatable attributes: `title, slug, body, meta_title, meta_description`, but `user_id` is not necessary translate and therefore did not add it to the $translatable array. It actually gives me an error. Tries to save user_id similar to this {"pl":"1", "en": "1"}. Please help me.

```
    class CreatePost extends CreateRecord
{
    use CreateRecord\Concerns\Translatable;

    protected static string $resource = PostResource::class;

    /**
     * @return array|Actions\Action[]|Actions\ActionGroup[]
     */
    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\LocaleSwitcher::make(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    protected function mutateFormDataBeforeCreate(array $data): array
    {
        $data['user_id'] = auth()->id();

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getRedirectUrl(): string
    {
        return $this->previousUrl ?? $this->getResource()::getUrl('filament.admin.resources.posts.index');
    }
}
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, HasTranslations;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'user_id',
        'meta_title',
        'meta_description',
        'body',
        'thumbnail',
        'active',
        'published_at',
    ];

    protected array $translatable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'body',
        'meta_title',
        'meta_description',
    ];
}
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WhaJ.png)

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmbZC.png)

Comment: Please update your question with more details like your create record code and your model.
With this information, there's nothing wrong.
Also please don't post code in image. Reading from images is hard and takes time for anyone who wants to test your code on their system.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, and it seems when you fill more than one languages at the same time, this happens, and this is an issue in the filament code.
Also, there's a PR that tries to fix this issue.

here a link to it: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/pull/9792

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in the filament code base that was fixed in the latest version (v3.0.101). [Here's the PR](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/pull/9792) that fixes this issue.

To resolve this issue, you need to use version 3.0.101 or higher.

Update the filament package by running `composer update` command.